# PyCharm cannot "Check out from Version Control"

Tags: github, pycharm

[image]I'm trying to check-out a public project from GitHub into Windows 10/PyCharm, but getting the error message: "Unable to create temporary file ... No such file or directory.  Index pack failed".  See attached screenshot.
I think it has something to do with permissions, but not sure how to resolve it so it doesn't pop-up every time I work on a GitHub project.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:
Download the package to C:\temp
Then copy/paste it to its final destination.
Not sure why this works, or why I was getting the original error message.